# how to use protected function geturl correctly? as data is pull from database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am new to asp.net and i wanted to know how to configure the protected function geturl.
my code behind :

```
     Protected Function Geturl(value As Object) As String

    Dim NCR As String = Convert.ToString("formid")


        If Mid(NCR, 4, 1) = 2 Then
            Return ("~/sapphire/ncrr2.aspx")
        Else
            Return ("~/sapphire/ncrr1.aspx")

        End If


End Function
```

due to some of the data that pulled from database is null i have encountered an error which is:

```
    Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid
```

how do i overcome this statement? how should i deal with the condition when the fetched data is null?

my code:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NCR" ItemStyle-Width="150px" >
    <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text ='<%#Eval("formid")%>'
 NavigateUrl = '<%# Eval("formid","~/sapphire/ncrr" + Mid(Eval("formid"), 4, 1) + ".aspx?formid={0}") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: That error has nothing to do with this function. The error is about not checking for NULL from the database, but this function has no database reads. Also, the function has a value parameter that you don't use.

Comment: You do know that there is an edit button for your question, right? It's just about impossible to read a code snippet from a comment.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn sorry i just started to use this forum
my bad  >< i have edit the code can you help me check?

Answer (score 1):

One of your `Eval()` expressions evaluates to `DBNull`. You need to find out why the database query returns NULL.

Comment: sorry joel can u explain more detail what is going on? because i just started to learn asp.net and my understanding is limited...